# Any competitive speech-to-text models?

Tags: machine-learning, sound, nlp

SpeechRecognize is not very useful compared to most voice transcription engines nowadays, simply too fragile and prone to errors.

I use Otter.ai currently, is there anything competitive to that (or Google voice typing) in v13 or in a third party paclet?

**Notes:**

- I'm looking to replace this: https://otter.ai/
- I've already tried the models on the wolfram network repo, results are not so good
- Interested in any leads on modern robust speech recognition implemented in Mathematica

Comment: I think you're right, MMA just isn't competitive with the latest tech...